# What does the pencil sign mean beside some people who comment?

Tags: support, comments

Sometimes I see a pencil sign beside some users who comment on a post. Here's an image:

[image]

What does the sign mean?

Comment: Try hovering over it... that should pretty much explain it.

Comment: No I tried it but nothing resulted.

Comment: It indicates the comment has been edited since it was originally posted... and if you hover over it, you'll get a tool-tip indicating *how many* times it has been edited.

Comment: I guess hover is not so easy on a mobile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It indicates that the comment has been edited.

If you're a moderator you can click on it to see the comment edit history.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not a moderator.....[grin]

Comment: `If you're a moderator you can click on it to see the comment edit history.` -- I was a moderator for ten years and never knew this.